# Twitter cannot read meta tags on a SSR vue.js app

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, twitter, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to implement vue ssr on a website, and I'm stuck with one major problem... While my ssr seems to be working (when I go to my page without js activated, I receive the fully rendered html, with all the prefetched data), Twitter cannot read my meta tags...

My url is https://testsite2.slickteam.fr/job/developpeur-fullstack-js-java (site is not fully working, still in development, but ssr is working, and meta tags are available on this page). There are the meta "twitter:description", "twitter:title", "twitter:image" and others, but when I test with the Twitter card validator tool (https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) with this url, it says "INFO:  Page fetched successfully WARN:  No metatags found".

I have the same issue with Linkedin, but Facebook seems to be working just fine...

Does anyone have an idea about what could cause Twitter not being able to read my meta tags?

I'm using the vue-server-renderer package, with an express nodejs server behind an nginx.

Thanks

Comment: Your SSR setup is not working correctly. If I visit the url you provided I receive an HTML file without any meta tags. Apparently they are inserted on client side. Interestingly, Facebook seems to be able to handle meta tags inserted on client side. Can you show us how you generate your meta tags?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @MarcRo , but are you sure you don't receive the meta tags?
When I do a `curl -s -A Twitterbot https://testsite2.slickteam.fr/job/developpeur-fullstack-js-java | grep twitter`, I can see, among other this tag : `<meta data-vue-meta="ssr" name="twitter:title" content="Developpeur Fullstack JS/JAVA – Slickteam">`

Comment: @MarcRo I do know dev tools, and it shows me that my meta tags are there... It looks like we're not receiving the same content...

Comment: @MarcRo Sure, and as I said I also tried to curl this url: I am receiving the meta tags.
This is the full content I am receiving, which i pasted from my network devtools tab: https://pastebin.com/ggwLX0fi

Comment: My apologies, it appears my eyes are not working in the moring. You are right. Another issue that might interfere is that your meta-tags are showing up multiple times. I have read somewhere that having multiple instances of a meta tag can cause issues.

Comment: No problem, all help is appreciated!
I don't see duplicated meta tags though: I have multiple meta, but all with a different name.
I was wondering if the attribute `data-vue-meta="ssr"` added by vue ssr to my tags could cause such an issue...

Comment: One with `data-vue-meta="ssr"` and one with `dta-vue-meta="1"`  -> https://pastebin.com/Myz2E7Tf

Comment: Found the solution, it was a missing header in my http response. I posted the solution below.
Thanks for investigating the issue!

Answer (score 4):

The http response do not include a `Content-Type: text/html` header.

In express js server, the solution is simple, simply add this line before sending the response:

```js
response.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
```